# How do I remove these ceiling diffuser flaps?

Tags: hvac

I need to move this diffuser away from the wall and can't figure out how to take out the flaps that are installed.  They don't have any screws on the inside that I can see.  Is there a trick to getting these out?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @jsotola Sorry that they were hard to see.  Here are some picture with more light: [Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/ZApoa5g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access that section from the attic and pull the screws then the assembly will drop down. You have an older damper from the days when they were not made to be removed so that ~1’ section of pipe with the damper needs to be removed. I am guessing at the 1’ but you can see the screws that connect the 90 to the damper. These are the screws that need to be removed. I think I see 3 total and there are usually 3-4.

Comment: Thank you! I thought maybe just the damper could come out.